# Eclipse crashes while loading Graphical Layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse, crash

I'm trying to load the graphical layout from an .xml. But when I do, Eclipse crashes and gives exit code = -1073740791. I've reistalled java several times (JDK 7) and still crashing. The app works just fine with no erros, also the text view of the layout works. This is so frustrating.. Any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the XML file and use "open with..." Try all the options until you find an editor that opens the file without crashing.

If it is really important to edit the file with the graphical editor, you may need to update your ADT tools or file a bug report.